# Notification when you're able to accept your own answer

Tags: feature-request, notifications, self-answer

This is a feature request for exactly one (1) notification when:

- You've posted an answer to your own question before the 48-hour self-answer accept time limit, and
- You have not accepted any answers on that question, and
- The time limit is up and you can now accept your own answer.

Given the relative rarity of self-answers, and the presumed common intent of posting a self-answer in order to accept it, I don't think this will lead to unwarranted notifications as long as the above rules are precisely obeyed.

Two days is a good bit of time to wait, and right now if you intend to accept your own answer, the only way to track it is to either put it on your calendar, or bookmark the post and periodically check it. A notification would get rid of the guesswork.

Comment: What benefit do you see of accepting your own answer any way?

Comment: @MartinSmith [Here is a good starting point for answering that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463). Plenty of links to read from there.

Comment: That seems to be about answering your own question not accepting answers. I have self answered questions that I have left unaccepted as I don't see any tangible benefit of accepting the answer. It doesnt alter the placement of the answer and will just put off other answers. Why the pressing need to do this as soon as possible that requires a reminder?

Comment: @MartinSmith If you would like to start a discussion about the utility of accepting one's own answer, you could post a new question about it here. Note that I have not expressed a pressing need to accept a self-answer "as soon as possible". :)

Comment: It's not off topic for this question. If there is no tangible benefit from doing it why should dev time be spent on this?